# How to zip own structure using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have my list structure and metafunctions for it.

```
template<int ...>
class MyList;

template<int H, int ... T>
class MyList<H, T ...> {
public:
    static const int Head = H;
    using Tail = MyList<T ...>;
};

template<>
class MyList<> {};

//list lenght
template<typename TL>
class Length {
public:
    static const int value = 1 + Length<typename TL::Tail>::value;
};

template<>
class Length<MyList<>> {
public:
    static const int value = 0;
};

//Add an element to front
template<int H, typename IL>
class IntCons;

template<int H, int... Tail>
class IntCons<H, MyList<Tail...>>{
public:
    using type = MyList<H, Tail...>;
};

//Generate list with N elements
template <int N, int ... Next>
class Generate : public Generate<N-1, N-1, Next...> { };

template <int ... Next>
struct Generate<0, Next ... > {
    using type = MyList<Next ... >;
};
```

I want to implement something as `std::transform`. I wrote metafunction `Calculate`. It takes 2 my lists as parameters an binary metafunction and it must take each element from each list and call my binary metafunction for this pair.

Binary metafunction

```
template<int x, int y>
struct Multiply {
    static int const value = x * y;
};
```

Calculate metafunction

```
template<typename L1, typename L2, template<int, int> class MetaF, class... Tail>
struct Calculate;

template<typename L1, typename L2, template<int, int> class MetaF, class... Tail>
struct Calculate : Calculate<typename L1::Tail, typename L2::Tail, MetaF, Tail...> {
static_assert( Length<L1>::value == Length<L2>::value,
    "The arguments of lists should be of the same size" );

    using type = IntCons<MetaF<L1::Head, L2::Head>::value, Tail...>;
};
```

If `L1 = MyList<2,2,3,3,5>` and `L2 = MyList<5,3,8,7,3>` I am waiting result `MyList<10, 6, 24, 21, 15>` But I have an error `parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’`
Tell me please how to fix it?

Comment: please post a [mcve] and include the complete error message in the question. gcc seems to get confused, but then with clang I didnt manage to get it compile for other reasons https://godbolt.org/z/za4391j8q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tip: Forget about recursion. Using recursion for template metaprogramming is the old complicated way. It is not necessary in most cases anymore. I have to admit, that your code is too complicated for me to comprehend. All you need is the list, the metafunction, partial specialization to infer `MyList` from a given instantiation (eg `MyList<2,2>`), then plug it back in, and for convenience a `_t` alias:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<int ...> class MyList;


template<int x, int y> struct Multiply {
    static int const value = x * y;
};

template<typename L1, typename L2, template<int, int> class MetaF>
struct Calculate;

template <template <int,int> class MetaF,template<int...> class ML,int... I1,int... I2>
struct Calculate< ML<I1...>,ML<I2...>,MetaF> {
    using type = ML< MetaF<I1,I2>::value ...>;
};

template <typename L1,typename L2, template<int,int> class MetaF>
using Calculate_t = typename Calculate<L1,L2,MetaF>::type;

int main() {
    using L1 = MyList<2,2>;
    using L2 = MyList<5,3>;
    using R = MyList<10,6>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<R, Calculate_t<L1,L2,Multiply>>;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/br73b3Pfx):

```
1
```

---

PS: If you do need to infer the length of the list, use partial specialization and the `sizeof...` operator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<int ...> class MyList;

template <class T> struct Length;
template <template <int...> class L,int...I>
struct Length<L<I...>> {
    static const size_t value = sizeof...(I);
};

template <class T> constexpr size_t Length_v = Length<T>::value;

int main() {
    using L1 = MyList<2,2>;
    std::cout << Length_v<L1>;
}
```

However, the simpler alternative is to have a `constexpr size_t length = sizeof...(I)` member in `MyList`. The above is only necessary if `MyList` itself does not have such member.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish you the best!